# Hibernate (Spring JPA) child entities removal

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Hibernate (Spring) and facing strange issue with removing child entities from the parent one.

Here is what I have:

Parent entity:

```
@Entity  
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<CompanyObject> companyObjects;
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
public class CompanyObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ObjectType type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    Company company;
}
```

Here is my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `company_object` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK__company` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__company` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And, also, I have the following `update` method:

```
// some code here
public void update(CompanyDto dto) {
    Company company = repository.getCompanyById(companyId);  
    repository.save(dto.merge(company));
}
// some code here  


public class CompanyDto {
    private List<CompanyObjectDto> companyObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public Company merge(Company company) {        
        company.getCompanyObjects().clear();
        for (CompanyObjectDto dto : companyObjects) {
            company.getCompanyObjects().add(dto.to(company));
        }
        return company;
    }
}

public class CompanyObjectDto {
    ObjectType type;

    public CompanyObject to(Company company) {
        CompanyObject object = new CompanyObject();
        object.setType(this.getType());
        object.setCompany(company);
        return object;
    }
}
```

And as soon as I launch `update` method, I get the following error: `java.sql.SQLWarning: Column 'company_id' cannot be null`. I investigated this a little bit and found out that if I comment out `company.getCompanyObjects().clear();` string it works ok, so it seems there is some problem with cascading delete action to company objects.

Could, please, somebody point me to my mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: When mapping bidirectionally, there should only be one @Joincolumn and you are missing a 'mappedby'.

Comment: This isn't what's causing the problem, but unless you add `, orphanRemoval = true` to that `OneToMany` annotation (where the list is), you will find that it never removes rows that you took off the list. Not having it is just what will cause you your next problem.

Comment: @Kirinya, thanks, that worked. Could you, please, submit your answer so I can mark it accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped your entities Company and CompanyObject bidirectionally, i.e. both entities have a relation to the other entity.

In this case, there should only be one @Joincolumn and one entity must be selected as the owning entity, with the other entity marking the relation with a 'mappedby' (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html).

Comment: Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are removing object's from `List` and then use the same `List` as a reference to your `Company` object. See below code :

```
private List<CompanyObjectDto> companyObjects = new ArrayList<>(); //Stmt 1
```

Above code is used to define list which will be reference in your below code :

```
company.getCompanyObjects().clear(); //It will clear out all objects
    for (CompanyObjectDto dto : companyObjects) { //Iterating over empty list defined in stmt 1.
        company.getCompanyObjects().add(dto.to(company));
    }
```

So your foreign key will always be null which is not permitted and throws exception.

And your code works when you comment out `List#clear` line because in that scenario, list already have some referenced objects which didn't modify.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but, unfortunately, not sure I understand. Are you saying that I need to assign `new ArrayList()` to `companyObjects` to make hibernate do what I want?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Actually `companyObjects` is not empty. There is some data came from web interface.